# Justifying formaly that $ \inf\{c\ge 0: \forall x\in V,\|Tx\|\le c\|x\| ,\forall x \in V\} =\sup\{\|Tx\|/\|x\|\: \forall x\in V,x \neq 0 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

$$\|T\|_1=\inf\{c\ge 0: \|Tx\|\le c\|x\| ,\forall x \in V\}=\inf\ S_1$$
$$\|T\|_2=\sup\{\|Tx\|/\|x\|\: \forall x\in V,x \neq 0 \}=\sup S_2$$

I am trying to formalize the equality between these two expresions. Intuitively is clear, but I am not sure how to write it.

My professor said "in $\|Tx\|/\|x\|\le c $  the sup of the left-hand side equals the inf of the right-hand side "

I know that if $f(x)\le g(y) \implies \sup f(x)\le \inf g(y)$ ...(*), but I don't think $\sup f(x)= \inf g(y)$  holds in general,

so how come it does in the particular case above?

So using (*) in $\|Tx\|/\|x\|\le c $ I have that $ \sup S_2 \le \inf\ S_1$. **How do I prove the inverse inequality, so that I can conclude   $ \sup S_2 = \inf\ S_1$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$S_1 := \{c \geq 0 : \textrm{for each $x \in V$ we have that $\|Tx\|\le c\|x\|$}\}, \\
S_2 := \left\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in V \setminus\{0\} \right\}.$$
Let's prove that $\inf(S_1) = \sup(S_2)$.

- If $c \in S_1$, then for each $x \in V \setminus \{0\}$ we have that $\|Tx\| \leq c\|x\|$, and so $$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} \leq c.$$ Hence, $c$ is an upper bound for $S_2$, so that $\sup(S_2) \leq c$. Since $c \in S_1$ was arbitrary, this means that $\sup(S_2)$ is a lower bound for $S_1$, whence $\sup(S_2) \leq \inf(S_1)$.
- Given $x \in V \setminus \{0\}$, from $$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} \leq \sup(S_2)$$ we see that $\|Tx\| \leq \sup(S_2)\|x\|$. Clearly, the latter also holds for $x=0$. Hence $\sup(S_2) \in S_1$, and then $\inf(S_1) \leq \sup(S_2)$.

Comment: Super clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Denote the left side by $m$.  Then $m-\frac  1n  \notin \{c: \|Tx\|\leq c\|x\| \,\forall x\}$ so there exists $x_n$ such that $\|Tx_n\|> (m-\frac 1n)\|x_n\| $. But then RHS $\geq \frac {\|Tx_n\|} {\|x_n\|}>m-\frac 1n$. Let $n \to \infty$ to finish.

[$m$ is $inf S_1$ and by RHS I mean $\sup S_2$. We have proved that $sup S_2 \geq \inf S_1$ as required].

Comment: I am not sure what you have proven. If by RHS you mean RHS=c and $m=\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$, you have proven that $c \ge \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$ which is just the initial problem. If I use the property I quoted, from this expresion I get  $\inf S_1 \ge \sup S_2$, and then the problem is proving the inverse inequality

Comment: @J.C.VegaO My $m$ is $inf S_1$ and by RHS I mean $\sup S_2$. I have proved that $sup S_2 \geq \inf S_1$.

Comment: I am trying to justify where you get this  $m-\frac  1n  \notin \{c: \|Tx\|\leq c\|x\| \,\forall x\}$ from, this doesn't come from the definition of $\sup S_2$ or $\inf S_1$ right?, which would be the natural way to start for me. Looks like applying such definitions doesn't help here

Comment: Any numebr less than the infimum of a set cannot belong to that set.  @J.C.VegaO

Comment: When you take the limit of $\frac {\|Tx_n\|} {\|x_n\|}$, we don't know if that limit is finite or if it converges, do we?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO RHS $\geq m-\frac 1n$ for all $n$ implies RHS $\geq m$.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure it doesn't matter what happens to the expresion in the middle at the limit